# Error Message: "It was not possible to locate sql library" in the Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I had to upload two files to show what is exactly happening.
Explaining: I am trying to implement a Java project in the NetBeans IDE.
But in the project, it is always appearing an error message:
"It was not possible to locate sql library netbeans":
[image]

I apologize because my NetBeans is installed in Portuguese language (which it is my native language, but I would like to solve this problem, please).

I downloaded and I installed the following sql packages inside same project:
[image]

But the error continues happening.
Please, anyone could help to solve this error?

Solution: "Create a new class library called SQL".
How to do this in the NetBeans, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in image 1 does not say "It was not possible to locate sql library netbeans", but rather "Unable to locate 'sql' library".

Also, the program gives you a possible solution:

"Problem: The project uses a class library called 'sql', but this class library is not found. Solution: Click Resolve to open the Library Manager and create a new class library called 'SQL'"

What does this library do?
Normal java has everything needed for using SQL with `java.sql`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Brentspine.
I downloaded and I installed the java-sql-jdbc-1.0.2.jar, but it did not work.